# Pythonic way to avoid using multiple IF statements when iterating and appending to a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I'm retrieving data from a Jira database, then saving the data to a Pandas data frame.  Here's my code:

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

cert_path = 'C:\\cert.crt'

start_date = '2020-10-01'
end_date = '2020-10-31'

# three different instances (each with their own schema)
a_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-A.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

b_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-B.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

c_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-C.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)


# define queries
query_1 = 'project = \"Test Project 1\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_2 = 'project = \"Test Project 2\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_3 = 'project = \"Test Project 3\" and issuetype = Defect and resolution = Resolved and releasedate >= {} and releasedate <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_4 = 'project = \"Test Project 4\" and issuetype = Enhancement and resolution = Done and completed >= {} and completed <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)


# fetch all issues from a given session for a given query
block_size = 100
block_num = 0


def get_all_issues(session, query):

    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'key' : issue.key,
            'type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
             }

        issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues


# list of queries, and the corresponding backend
queries = [
    (a_session, query_1),
    (a_session, query_2),
    (b_session, query_3),
    (c_session, query_4),
]


# loop over each pair of session and query, calling the get_all_issues function, and save the dataframe we get each time
dataframes = []

for session, query in queries:
    dataframe = get_all_issues(session, query)
    dataframes.append(dataframe)

# concatenate all data frames

all = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

This code works just fine (because the 4 field names in the `d` dict are common to `a_session`, `b_session`, and `c_session`).

The problem arises when I try to introduce a custom field that might be present in, say, `a_session` but not in `b_session` or `c_session`.

For example:

```
for issue in all_issues:
    d = {
        'key' : issue.key,
        'type' : issue.fields.type,
        'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
        'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution,
        'system_change' : issue.fields.custom_field_123,  # only applicable to a_session and b_session
        'system_resources' : issue.fields.custom_field_456,  # only applicable to c_session
        'system_backup' : issue.fields.custom_field_789   # only applicable to b_session and c_session
         }
```

`custom_field_123` exists in `a_session` and `b_session`, but not in `c_session`.

`custom_field_456` exists only in `c_session`.

And, `custom_field_789` exists in `b_session` and `c_session`.

Running the code with this expanded dictionary results in the following error: `AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'custom_field_123'`.

Other than using IF statements, is there a Pythonic way to allocate the only the **valid field names** in the `d` dictionary to the relevant sessions?  For example, as `a_session`/`query_2` is running, only consider `custom_field_123` (because that's the only one that's valid) and DISREGARD `custom_field_456` and `custom_field_789` (because passing these would result in the error message above).

Thanks in advance for any help you can give this Python novice!

Comment: How/why is this a `pandas` issue though? you could pass in the list of custom fields separately to your query and then build your json accordingly

Comment: It’s not necessarily a Pandas issue. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Also, I don’t believe there is json here...

Comment: the only reason i mentioned pandas because you have it tagged. also i meant dictionary

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by passing a custom dictionary? How and where would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a dictionary including the four (4) fields common to all `session` objects, then use `if hasattr()`, as follows:

```
d = {
    'key' : issue.jira_key,
    'type' : issue.fields.issue_type,
    'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
    'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
}
fields = issue.fields  # For brevity
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_123"):
    d['system_change'] = fields.custom_field_123
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_456"):
    d['system_resources'] = fields.custom_field_456
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_789"):
    d['system_backup'] = fields.custom_field_789
```